# What's faster in Android: sending data to a WebView with loadUrl or retrieving it from the WebView with a JavascriptInterface?

Tags: java, javascript, android, performance, webview

I'm writing an Android app where I have to **transfer many integers from my app's Java code to the Javascript in a WebView**, so that they are displayed to the user.

I see two ways of transferring this string:

- **Using loadUrl** on the WebView:

With an array `data` containing ints, I would use this code to transfer them to my webview.

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:loadData(" + data[0] + ");"); // data[0] is an int
webView.loadUrl("javascript:loadData(" + data[1] + ");"); // data[1] is an int
// etc.
```

- **Using JavascriptInterface**:

I have a Java class that holds the `data` array and exposes a method named `getData(int x)`, which just returns the value of `data[x]`. I can declare a JavascriptInterface so that method is visible to my Javascript code, which can then call it and get the data:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(backend, "dataBackend");
```

My question is this: **which approach is faster?** I imagine that if I have many elements in `data`, executing a lot of `loadUrl()` calls would be slow and buggy. But does the alternative work faster?

Answer (score 0):

In general both loadUrl and jsInterface are not supposed to transfer large amounts of data. But you can try building one large string from those integers and using it instead.